# Using a handler inside a thread called from a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I have a thread which creates a handler. The thread is called from a service. The issue is since its called from a service, I cannot use Activity.runOnUiThread(). I only have access to the Context not Activity.

I get this error when I create the handler,

```
11-09 13:34:52.355: W/System.err(20974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
11-09 13:34:52.359: W/System.err(20974):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
```

Here is the code:

```
public void runTask() {


        Handler handler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                //HANDLER CODE
            }
        };

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }
```

The code might seem odd because I have removed a bunch of statements.

Answer (score 1):

A Handler requires a [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) in its Thread. Simply call `Looper.prepare()` while initializing the Thread and when you are ready start the Looper with `Looper.loop()`.

```
public void runTask() {
    Looper.prepare();

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //HANDLER CODE
        }
    };

    Looper.loop();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

Alternatively you could also use a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) which initializes the Looper for you.